# GIS Analysis Services for third party DBMS

Tags: qgis, arcgis-platform, database

In our database environment (gemstoneDB - smalltalk) we would like use some of the core features of GIS Tools like intersecting shapes, find nearest polygons, create buffer around lines and points etc.

We started to implement some of those features by writing the algos on our own. As it goes down well for our users, we would like to offer more and more GIS features in the future.

Can you recommend any best practice on how to implement a third party GIS tool, which can serve this features? Workflow would be sending geojson to the service and getting back whatever requested (in geojson). So it is not only about viewing the data on tile layers but really getting the data as vector data so that we can rejoin it in the database.

**EDIT**

sorry for not beeing more clearly. I added tags for qgis and arcgis because the company I work for is open for commercial as well as open source techs. I recently found turf.js and we will give it a shot on nodejs. maybe there is something similar like turf - but this looks very promising at the moment.

Comment: You have tags for QGIS and ArcGIS but make no mention of either in your question. How are they related to what you are asking?

Comment: Any "spatial_enabled" database (like SQLServer 2008 and laters,Oracle8,postGreSQL,...) has built-in functions and procedures for spatial-analysis.The simple one is intersec.For example in SQLServer function STIntersecs(anotherGeometry) return intersect relation result for two geometries.Or STContains show if a geometry contains another one.You are blessed if your databse implements OGC(open GIS consortium) specifications for geospatial functions.I suggest using built-in function of these features instead of rewritting all those complicated codes.

Comment: thank you for your feedback - but we are using a gemstoneDB which has no spatial / GIS Features. Therfore we are looking for other ways to do spatial calculations